Adding LAN to opnsense interface on hetzner
I am a newbie in opnsense. I installed opnsense on hetzner. I want to add LAN to interface but I can't find LAN interface on the assignment menu. What I can add is opt1. How do I add LAN to interfaces?


What do you want to achieve? Lan is just a name that you can assign. It carries no function.

it is working now. thanks @vidarlo

if you solved the problem I please you to add an answer and accept it 24h later on else we will be reminded until the end of the universe to solve this problem

Go to Interfaces > Assignment > Add wan1 > save and apply changes
Go to interfaces > opt1 > enable interface > IPv4 Configuration Type to DHCP > save > apply changes
